# Correctness of algorithm for finding diameter of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, proof-of-correctness

I needed an algorithm to find the diameter of a tree, and found the following: Pick an arbitrary vertex y and run breadth-first search to find the farthest vertex from y, call it x, then run BFS on x to find the farthest vertex from x, call it z, this distance d(x,z) is the diameter.

However, I do not understand why x must necessarily be in a vertex-pair that has the largest diameter. I have found [Proof of correctness: Algorithm for diameter of a tree in graph theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010472/proof-of-correctness-algorithm-for-diameter-of-a-tree-in-graph-theory) where proof by contradiction is suggested, assuming some d(u,v) which is bigger than d(x,z). A case distinction can then be made between these cases:

1. The path from u to v intersects the path from the root to x
2. The path from u to v does not intersect the path from the root to x

Knowing that there is some vertex h on the path from u to v which is the 'highest' (closest to the root), it should be possible to prove for both these cases that d(u,v) cannot be bigger than d(x,z).

But I don't understand what the 'root' is (is this y?) and despite the hints I cannot see why it is true. I don't need a formal proof, but I would like to understand why the algorithm is correct.

Comment: You might get better traction on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Answered on the other question; closing this one as a duplicate.